# How can I create unit test for void method which just change data and save it

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, clean-architecture

I have some handler(in this example I just use controller):

```
@RestController
public class MessageController {

    private final TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
    private final Operation operation;
    private final MessageLogService messageLogService;

    public MessageController(TaskExecutor taskExecutor, Operation operation, MessageLogService messageLogService) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
        this.operation = operation;
        this.messageLogService = messageLogService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/process")
    public String handleMessage(MessageRequest messageRequest){

        MessageLog messageLog = messageLogService.createNewMessageLog();

        taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                operation.process(messageLog.getGuid(), messageRequest);
            } catch (MessageLogDoesNotExistException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        return "REQUEST_QUOTED";
    }
}
```

1. I receive some request.
2. I create new `MessageLog` in DB with status "NEW" and some default(and some data from the request in the real project) values and save.
3. I send `messageRequest` and `MessageLog's guid` to the `operation` in the executor and return sync response "REQUEST_QUOTED" immediately.

```
@Service
public class MessageOperation implements Operation {

        private final MessageLogService messageLogService;

        public MessageOperation(MessageLogService messageLogService) {
            this.messageLogService = messageLogService;
        }

        @Transactional
        @Override
        public void process(String guid, MessageRequest messageRequest) throws MessageLogDoesNotExistException {

            MessageLog messageLog = messageLogService.getOne(guid);

            if (messageLog == null)
                throw new MessageLogDoesNotExistException();

            try {
                Message message = createMessage(messageRequest);
                messageLog.setStatus("SUCCESS");
                messageLog.setMessage(message);
            } catch (MessageCreationException e) {
                messageLog.setStatus("FAIL");
                messageLog.setErrorCode(e.getCode());
            }
            messageLogService.save(messageLog);
        }

        private Message createMessage(MessageRequest messageRequest) throws MessageCreationException {
            //logic
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Into `operation` I create the message and bind it with messageLog. If I create and bind success - I set status 'SUCCESS' or 'FAIL' if not. And just save messageLog.

How can I create `Unit test` for `operation's` method `process`? It is void.

1) I get a request from the client

2) delegate the request to the new thread for the async process

3) return sync response.

And I don't understand how can I create a unit test for `public void process(String guid, MessageRequest messageRequest)`

Comment: This is better suited for an [integration test](http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/integration-testing/), but you could also use libraries such as [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) if you really insist on unit testing that method.

Comment: In an unit test you will only need to assert you actually called the external services your tested service uses, like your method process() calls messageLogService, you need to assert that call and mock the response of the service as well, there will be a point where you call process and you will get your mocked response in accordance at the expectations rules

Answer (score 1):

In this case for `MessageOperation` I recommend using `Mockito` https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations library for mocking the class attribute

```java
@Mock
private final MessageLogService messageLogService;
```

Then in your unit test you use the `verify()`method to check that expected behaviour has happened. (save is called correctly for example).

I would also mock the response of `getOne` to fit your need

```java
MessageLog messageLog = messageLogService.getOne(guid);
```

for example

```java
MessageLog messageLog = new MessageLog();
when(messageLogService.getOne(eq("THE GUID YOU GIVE IN THE METHDO CALL"))).thenReturn(messageLog);
```

That way since you have the object reference to `MessageLog`you can check for the status in the test code:

```java
assertEquals("SUCCESS", messageLog.getStatus());
```

And use verify to check that the save method is called correctly:

```java
verify(messageLogService).save(same(messageLog));
```

About the matchers I used https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argument-matchers